# Is it possible to stop my result from showing until all boxes are ticked?

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for some help. I recently set up a questionnaire on a webpage and somebody previously helped me to make my result section display when all the yes or no boxes are ticked by the user.

However he has changed my code quite a bit and I dont quite understand how I can modify it further so that I can prevent the pink or grey results section from displaying until 4 boxes are ticked in total.

Currently when you tick any box, the pink or grey box appears even though you have only answered one question, but I am hoping to prevent that from happening until a yes or no is ticked from each section.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="center">
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
    <div class="left2">
<div class="left question">Do you pay your businesses gas/electric bills?</div>
        <div class="right answer">
            <div class="leftradio">
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="yes1" value="yes1" name="iCheck1">
                </input>
            </div>
            <div class="rightradio">
                <label>No</label>
                <input type="radio" id="no1" name="iCheck1"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right2">
    <div class="left question">Has someone lived within or upstairs for at least 6 months, within the last 4 years?</div>
        <div class="right answer">
            <div class="leftradio">
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="yes2" value="yes2" name="iCheck2"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="rightradio">
                <label>No</label>
                <input type="radio" id="no2" name="iCheck2">
                </input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left2">
<div class="left question">Have you been supplied by any of these companies below in the past 4 years?</div>
        <div class="right answer">
            <div class="leftradio">
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="yes3" value="yes3" name="iCheck3"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="rightradio">
                <label>No</label>
                <input type="radio" id="no3" name="iCheck3"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right2">
    <div class="left question">Do you own a car?</div>
        <div class="right answer">
            <div class="leftradio">
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="yes4" value="yes4" name="iCheck4"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="rightradio">
                <label>No</label>
                <input type="radio" id="no4" name="iCheck4">
                </input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div style="display: table; width:100%; text-align: center; padding-top: 34px">
      <div class="row">
    <div id="correct">
        <div class="boxtext">YOU QUALIFY!</div>
    </div>
    <div id="incorrect"><div class="boxtext"><span style="font-weight:bold">X</span> SORRY YOU DO NOT QUALIFY</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#correct {display: none; background: hotpink; padding: 20px;}
#incorrect {display: none; background: grey; padding: 20px;}
```

JQuery:

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
var par=$(this).parent().parent();
if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('no')>=0 && !par.hasClass('inValid')){
    par.toggleClass('inValid');
}else if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('yes')>=0 && par.hasClass('inValid')){
    par.toggleClass('inValid');
         }
if(!par.hasClass('done'))
    par.toggleClass('done');
if($('.done').length==4&&$('.inValid').length>0){
    $("#correct").hide();
    $("#incorrect").show();
}else{
    $("#correct").show();
    $("#incorrect").hide();
}
```

});

Could somebody give me a push in the right direction or explain how I can go about doing this?

I also have a fiddle see: http://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/9x60bgmf/2/

Comment: You could do it with the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) operator in jQuery. Just checking if each input is set to yes, before displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there, but the commented area below is the area which was executing on EVERY input click. I have restricted it by checking the amount of input boxes that are checked.

```
    $("input" ).on( "click", function() {
        var par=$(this).parent().parent();
        if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('no')>=0 && !par.hasClass('inValid')){
            par.toggleClass('inValid');
        }else if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('yes')>=0 && par.hasClass('inValid')){
            par.toggleClass('inValid');
        }
        if(!par.hasClass('done'))
            par.toggleClass('done');

        // THIS IF STATEMENT CHECKS TO SEE IF THE TOTAL AMOUNT OF CHECKED BOXES EQUALS 4    
        if($("input:checked").size() == 4) {

            // THIS BIT WAS EXECUTING ON EVERY CLICK BEFORE
            if($('.done').length==4&&$('.inValid').length>0){
                $("#correct").hide();
                $("#incorrect").show();
            }else{
                $("#correct").show();
                $("#incorrect").hide();
            } 
        }
    });
```

You may want to make the selector input in the jQuery more specific though if you are putting it on a complex page, for example, giving the relevant inputs a class.

Here is a link to the working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x60bgmf/3/)

Comment: nice 1 you deserve 1 +

Comment: Hi thanks this has really helped me, I was messing around with it for an hour lol

Comment: anytime @user3018817 :)

Answer (score 0):

look at this fiddle I just modify your code with your need.

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x60bgmf/4/)

modified js code

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    var par=$(this).parent().parent();
    if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('no')>=0 && !par.hasClass('inValid')){
        par.toggleClass('inValid');
    }else if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('yes')>=0 && par.hasClass('inValid')){
        par.toggleClass('inValid');
             }
    if(!par.hasClass('done'))
        par.toggleClass('done');

    if($('input[type="radio"][name="iCheck1"]:checked').size()!=0 &&
      $('input[type="radio"][name="iCheck2"]:checked').size()!=0 &&
        $('input[type="radio"][name="iCheck3"]:checked').size()!=0 &&
       $('input[type="radio"][name="iCheck4"]:checked').size()!=0){

        $("#correct").show();
        $("#incorrect").hide();
    }else {
        $("#correct").hide();
        $("#incorrect").show();
    }
});
```